# python unittests with multiple test classes

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am working on Python unittests. I want to segregate my test cases based on the pages/modules. When working with unittest.TestCase, every class need to have a setUp method to initialize my page instance. This causes a new instance of browser to open with each test case class run. 
What can I do to run all the testcase classes under the same browserinstance once after the other?

**logintests.py**

```
browser_input = input("Select a Browser: Firefox, Chrome, IE\n").lower()
class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        browser = BrowserMachine(cls)
        cls.driver = browser.open_browser(cls, browser_input)
        cls.LoginPage = LoginPage(cls.driver)
        cls.HomePages = HomePages(cls.driver)

    def testcaseA(self):
```

**homepagetests.py**

```
class HomepageTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        browser = BrowserMachine(cls)
        cls.driver = browser.open_browser(cls, LT.browser_input)
        cls.LoginPage = LoginPage(cls.driver)
        cls.HomePages = HomePages(cls.driver)

    def testcaseB(self):
```

Comment: You are giving each instance of `BrowserMachine` a different parameter upon construction. You cannot do that if you have only one instance. Better make up your mind and decide what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Make `BrowserMachine` into a global variable (module-level; you might create a separate module for that.  Both classes  should then use it.

The  `BrowserMachine` then  will not be able to refer to the class (`cls`) but you want only one   `BrowserMachine` anyone, not one per class.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a main `BrowserPage` or `BrowserMachine` class that is a unittest.TestCase and have every other page class inherit that.

That way you can declare all your methods or properties (like defining individualized `find_by`, `click_by`, `scroll_to` etc... actions) in the BrowserPage class. Your page classes will be able to call those methods and properties or override them (something like `click_login` for your `LoginTests` class, that uses your `BrowserPage`'s `click_by` method on a specific login string), have indivudual SetUp and TearDown.

If you declare your driver in the main classe's setUpClass and `quit` it in it's tearDownClass, you should be able to use the same webppage across your tests. Unless you need to spawn new instances of it in other page classes (to perform some action in the background for example, while your main test is running).